# Why does flatlist with async data only render Items after a hot reload?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Premise: Need another set of eyes to look at this. I have a flatlist which renders data from async storage (realm.js). Its an async task which receives an object, converts it to an array, and sets state once it has the result.

Problem: the flatlist will not render the items on the initial load. im logging both the result from the async task, and the state variable once its updated. they log fine. the flatlist *only* renders items aftre a hot-reload (saving a file). if the app is re-bundled and run, it will not load on screen mount

screen with flatlist:

```
export default List = ({navigation}) => {
  const { state } = useData()
  const [list, setList] = useState(null)
  const [listRefreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)

  const init = async () => {
    const generatedList = await generateList()
    console.log(`list refreshing:`, listRefreshing, `gen'd invoices`, generatedInvoices)
    setList(Object.values(generatedList))
    setRefreshing(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    init()
  }, [state.listItemCount, listRefreshing])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (list != null) {
      console.log(`list generated:`, list)
    }
  }, [invoices])

  return (
    <ScreenContainer>
      <FlatList 
        data={list == null ? [] : list}
        style={styles.list}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.listContent}
        refreshing={listRefreshing}
        onRefresh={() => setRefreshing(true)}
        keyExtractor={(item) => {
          return (
              item.toString() +
              new Date().getTime().toString() +
              Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(new Date().getTime())).toString()
          );
        }}
        ListEmptyComponent={() => <Text>No Items Yet</Text>}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => <ListItem data={item} key={index} navigation={navigation}/>}
      />
    </ScreenContainer>
    )
}
```

the `generateList()` is somewhat long-winded, but it reads async data using realm.js, and returns data with structure like:

```
{
"00001": { id: '', account: {}},
"00002": {id: '', account: {}}
}
```

here are the logs:

> list refreshing: false gen'd invoices {"111118": {"account":
> [Object]}, "759": {"account": [Object]}}
>
> invoices generated: [{"account": [Object]}, {"account": [Object]}]

What am i missing on this one?

Comment: shouldn't `setRefreshing(false)` inside `init()` be `setRefreshing(true)`?

Comment: no because when its set in `init`, data is retrieved and set in state, so its done refreshing. thats outside of scope from this question anyway, unless youre surmising the value of `refreshing` is somehow affecting the rendering of the items? @Noriller

Comment: Can you also add a log just before the `return ( <ScreenContainer ...` block with the list? Also, why such complex key in keyExtractor? Isn't the id of each element returned by realm adequate?
One more thing, isn't listRefreshing dependency parameter unneeded and possibly problematic inside useEffect that contains init() ? I can possibly see a loop there if refreshing is set to true at some point

Comment: @angelos_lex logging right before the return logs the data as expected

Comment: Do you have same behavior after simplifying the keyExtractor to something like index.toString(), and removing the ScreenContainer parent?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the keyextractor or refreshing state. i modified it to a class component without changing any of that and it worked the way its expected @angelos_lex